# Spanning set lemma - not sure if correct

Tags: linear-algebra

I came up with and "proved" this lemma whilst solving a problem:

If $S \subseteq \text{span {W}}$, then $\text{span {S}} \subseteq \text{span{W}}$

It makes intuitive sense to me, but, I'm not sure if it actually holds true (and I'm not sure if my prove is bogus because of some missed assumption).

What's your opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $s \in \mbox{span}{S}$, then it is a finite linear combination of things in $S$.  But everything of $S$ can be written as a finite linear combination of things in $W$ as $S \subseteq \mbox{span}{W}$ so $s$ is a finite linear combination of a finite linear combination of things in $W$, which happens to also be a finite linear combination of things in $W$.  Throw in symbols to make it a bit more formal

Comment: So, the lemma is correct? That was roughly the proof I had, but, more formal.

Comment: Yes assuming that is the definition of span you are going by.  In some contexts, you may also include various other vectors which are the limit of an infinite sum in a Banach space or something.  If we are just accepting finite linear combinations of things as things inside the span, then the lemma is fine.